# Is there a way to initialize the items in a SelectBox from an array in Qooxdoo?

Tags: qooxdoo

This seems basic, but can't seem to find a way to implement this: I would like to initialize a SelectBox from an array

```
var array = ["item1","item2"...]
```

instead of having to loop through ListItems

```
var selectBox = new qx.ui.form.SelectBox();
var test = ["item1", "item2"];
for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
    var tempItem = new qx.ui.form.ListItem(test[i]);
    selectBox.add(tempItem);
}
```

Is there a way to do that in Qooxdoo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off a more elegant version of your loop:

```
var selectBox = new qx.ui.form.SelectBox();
test = ["item1", "item2"];

test.forEach(function(obj) {
    selectBox.add(new qx.ui.form.ListItem(obj));
}, this);
```

But you should take a look at the data binding documentation in Qooxdoo ([Link to documentation](http://manual.qooxdoo.org/1.6.x/pages/data_binding/data_binding.html)). When using this you have a solution like this:

```
var selectBox = new qx.ui.form.SelectBox();
test = ["item1", "item2"];

new qx.data.controller.List(new qx.data.Array(test), selectBox);
```

When working with controllers you get some more interesting features like easy binding a change event to other widgets etc.